# 500 Error when trying to view MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, mybb

Thanks in advance for any help with this. I've just installed myBB forum and then added users from my existing website to it directly to the MySQL db. (not through the forum admin panel)

This worked fine. All members are added.

What doesn't work now is trying to VIEW the table "mybb_users" via phpmyadmin. It takes forever to load and then just throws a 500 internal server error. Oddly enough, the forum itself works fine and users show up no problem.

After much googling and tinkering nothing was working to fix this so I decided to test something and created an identical table named mybb_userss (double s) and inserted the same members the same way into this new table.

I can view that one just fine! Everything is the same except the name of the table.

But, if I rename it to mybb_users (without the double s) I once again won't be able to view it without the 500 error.

The specific error says this: 
"Error in Processing Request
Error code: 500
Error text: Internal Server Error"

This is sort of driving me up the wall, if anyone has any ideas about what could be happening here I'd be super grateful.

I know this isn't a myBB support forum, but I don't feel it has anything to do specifically with the forum (but could be wrong), it seems to be a weird mysql situation.

Comment: See at server error log to find specific error and line that generate it

Comment: Do you have SSH access? if so, have you tried querying the table straight from console? You can also try running a manual limited query in phpMyAdmin from the SQL tab: SELECT * FROM mybb_users LIMIT 5. If that works, try increasing the LIMIT. It could be that phpMyAdmin is trying to display all rows hanging up the request.

Comment: Both of those suggestions worked! I can do a query with a limit and it will work both when accessing phpmyadmin with WHM and via the reg cpanel. Which is good. I can access the table via the WHM cpanel link and it will load without a limit, but for some reason it still won't show all the entries without an error in the regular cpanel for that site, but I suppose if everything else works I won't be picky, I'll just make my edits via WHM. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score -4):

In console execute the select of table

```
select * from table
```

and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>